# Copying sheet to last row of a sheet from another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I'm stuck in this block of code that copies sheet("Newly Distributed") to the last row of sheet("Source") from another workbook. The error is runtime error 9. What's wrong with my code? Any response would be appreciated.

```
Private Sub copylog3()

Dim lRow As Long
Dim NextRow As Long, a As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim ret
Dim log As Workbook

lRow = Sheets("Macro Template").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Range("A7:AM" & lRow).Copy
Sheets("Newly Distributed").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

ret = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Workbooks (*.xls, .xlsx*),*.xls, .xlsx*", _
                                  Title:="Select data file for Monitoring Log")

Set log = Workbooks.Open(ret)

'----Copy to monitoring log

NextRow = log.Sheets("Source").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
a = NextRow
i = 1

Do Until Sheets("Newly Distributed").Cells(i, 1) = ""

    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 1).Value = Sheets("Newly Distributed").Cells(i, 1).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 2).Value = Sheets("Newly Distributed").Cells(i, 2).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 3).Value = Sheets("Newly Distributed").Cells(i, 3).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 4).Value = Sheets("Newly Distributed").Cells(i, 4).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 5).Value = Sheets("Newly Distributed").Cells(i, 5).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 6).Value = Sheets("Newly Distributed").Cells(i, 6).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 7).Value = Sheets("Newly Distributed").Cells(i, 7).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 8).Value = Sheets("Newly Distributed").Cells(i, 8).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 9).Value = Sheets("Newly Distributed").Cells(i, 9).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 10).Value = Sheets("Newly Distributed").Cells(i, 10).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 11).Value = Sheets("Newly Distributed").Cells(i, 11).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 12).Value = Sheets("Newly Distributed").Cells(i, 12).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 13).Value = Sheets("Newly Distributed").Cells(i, 13).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 14).Value = Sheets("Newly Distributed").Cells(i, 14).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 15).Value = Sheets("Newly Distributed").Cells(i, 15).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 16).Value = Sheets("Newly Distributed").Cells(i, 16).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 17).Value = Sheets("Newly Distributed").Cells(i, 17).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 18).Value = Sheets("Newly Distributed").Cells(i, 18).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 19).Value = Sheets("Newly Distributed").Cells(i, 19).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 20).Value = Sheets("Newly Distributed").Cells(i, 20).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 21).Value = Sheets("Newly Distributed").Cells(i, 21).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 22).Value = Sheets("Newly Distributed").Cells(i, 22).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 23).Value = Sheets("Newly Distributed").Cells(i, 23).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 24).Value = Sheets("Newly Distributed").Cells(i, 24).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 25).Value = Sheets("Newly Distributed").Cells(i, 25).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 26).Value = Sheets("Newly Distributed").Cells(i, 26).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 27).Value = Sheets("Newly Distributed").Cells(i, 27).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 28).Value = Sheets("Newly Distributed").Cells(i, 28).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 29).Value = Sheets("Newly Distributed").Cells(i, 29).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 30).Value = Sheets("Newly Distributed").Cells(i, 30).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 31).Value = Sheets("Newly Distributed").Cells(i, 31).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 32).Value = Sheets("Newly Distributed").Cells(i, 32).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 33).Value = Sheets("Newly Distributed").Cells(i, 33).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 34).Value = Sheets("Newly Distributed").Cells(i, 34).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 36).Value = Sheets("Newly Distributed").Cells(i, 39).Value

i = i + 1
a = a + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: In which line do you get the error? VBA Runtime Error 9 is "subscript out of range".

Comment: in this line     log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 1).Value = Sheets("Newly Distributed").Cells(i, 1).Value

Comment: And what's the value of "a" at that point?

Comment: the last row of sheet(Source) from workbook log

Comment: Is it possible that you are running out of rows in the destination sheet?

Comment: I don't think so. I only want to copy the values to the last row of the sheet from another workbook.

Comment: The reason you get that error was due to you open the new workbook and that workbook did not have the worksheet called "Newly Distributed" . you need set the workbook point to that worksheet only can work perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I mentioned in my comment 
Note: in future, you can using for loop to go through the column index.

```
Option Explicit
Dim WB1 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet

Private Sub copylog3()

Dim lRow As Long
Dim NextRow As Long, a As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim ret
Dim log As Workbook

Set WB1 = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = WB1.Worksheets("Newly Distributed")

lRow = Sheets("Macro Template").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Range("A7:AM" & lRow).Copy
ws1.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

ret = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Workbooks (*.xls, .xlsx*),*.xls, .xlsx*", _
                                  Title:="Select data file for Monitoring Log")

Set log = Workbooks.Open(ret)

'----Copy to monitoring log

NextRow = log.Sheets("Source").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
a = NextRow
i = 1

Do Until ws1.Cells(i, 1) = ""

    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 1).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 1).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 2).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 2).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 3).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 3).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 4).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 4).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 5).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 5).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 6).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 6).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 7).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 7).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 8).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 8).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 9).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 9).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 10).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 10).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 11).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 11).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 12).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 12).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 13).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 13).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 14).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 14).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 15).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 15).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 16).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 16).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 17).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 17).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 18).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 18).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 19).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 19).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 20).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 20).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 21).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 21).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 22).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 22).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 23).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 23).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 24).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 24).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 25).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 25).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 26).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 26).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 27).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 27).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 28).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 28).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 29).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 29).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 30).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 30).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 31).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 31).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 32).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 32).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 33).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 33).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 34).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 34).Value
    log.Sheets("Source").Cells(a, 36).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 39).Value

i = i + 1
a = a + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. By the way, is there any way to do this without doing any loop? The execution is very slow.

Comment: you may calculate to the end of row and copy them at once like what you did at the beginning of the code. Meanwhile , you may set `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`  to enhance the script performance.

Comment: I get it now. But how can I use the For Loop if I'm going to skip a column?

Comment: Using conditional checking --> IF to check whether the cell contain any value or not